# Replace '+' in current page URL with '%2B' or space

Tags: php

I have a URL generated via form submission with passed variables. I won’t go into detail but the ‘+’ in the URL breaks the system, so I would like to replace it with ‘%2B’.

However, every method I have tried so far has not worked. I have tried the various PHP URL decode methods and none of them work, since they replace other characters in the URL which again breaks it.

**The URL looks like this:**

```
www.domain.com/catalog/search.php?sort_by=relevance&some_filter%5B%5D=filter+term
```

I have also tried getting the current page URL and using str_ireplace to replace the ‘+’ characters with regular spaces or ‘%2B’, all to no avail.

I would appreciate any help!

Thanks

Comment: [`urlencode`](http://php.net/urlencode); depending on how & where you generate the URL.

Comment: are you using something like codeigniter?

Comment: Sounds like a terrible system if `+` breaks it...

Comment: fix the system to work with any symbols in URL, other way you have potential security hole or at least public accessible way to break your system

Comment: @ignacio - by default codeigniter (and possibly other frameworks) disallow + in the URI for whatever reason. You can allow it pretty easily by adjusting the config file, which is why I asked OP if they're using CI. In general I agree with you cause everyone making a sane search utility will use GET and + will be in there, so default installation craps out. But it is an easy fix if OP is using CI at all.

Comment: @Lashane - it doesn't break the system as such. Basically leaves a checkbox or two ticked that shouldn't be, so doesn't cause any security issues.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using php, try urlencode() and urldecode()

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

It will save you the headache of replacing the characters (which are then replaced).

Here is a more complete example close to your use case.

```
<?php

$foo = str_replace('+','%2B', 'www.domain.com/catalog/search.php?sort_by=relevance&some_filter%5B%5D=filter+term');

echo urldecode($foo);
```

Comment: *"If you're using php, try urlencode() and urldecode()"* - I think it's clear ;-)

Comment: Can't quite get this to work - the form action is set to `www.domain.com/catalog/search.php?start=0` and the rest of the URL is generated via passed variables. Using `urldecode()` on this URL does not help. What I need to be able to do is effectively use this function on the 'current URL' so that it is adaptable. Thanks

Comment: So when the form is submitted to www.domain.com/catalog/search.php?start=0&sort_by=relevance&some_filter%5B%5D=filter+term, what happens?

Comment: In search.php maybe try urldecode on the parameter. urldecode($_GET['some_filter']); for example